# Saving JSON received through a controller to the database MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

Hi guys I have started to use visual studio from about 4-5 days now, I had a lot of doubts, Thanks to the Stack Overflow Community I have gained a bit more knowledge. 
I am trying to POST JSON to the controller and save it to a database using Model Binding.

I am able to POST the JSON to the controller using the following ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:' + $(this).attr('id') + '&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',
        success: function (data) {

        **ajaxresult.push(data);**
        debugger;

        table.empty();
        table.append("<thead><tr><th>Avatar</th><th>Name</th><th>Score</th><th>URL</th><th>Updated at</th></tr></thead>");
        $.each(data.items, function (i, object) {

            var row = $('<tr>').addClass('table-primary');
            row.append('<td><img src=' + object.owner.avatar_url + 'height=50px width=50px/></td>');
            row.append('<td>' + object.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.score + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.url + '</td>' + '<td>' + object.updated_at + '</td>');
            table.append(row);

            **ajaxresult[i] = { "Avatar": object.owner.avatar_url, "Name": object.name, "Score": object.score, "URL": object.url, "Updatedat": object.updated_at };**
        });
        **var myJSON = JSON.stringify(ajaxresult);**
        table.append('</table>');
        $('table').replaceWith(table);
        debugger;
        console.log(myJSON);
         $.ajax({

                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    datatype:'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:60294/Git/Updateto',
                    **data: myJSON,**
             success: function (data) {
                 alert('Post Succesful');
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('error');
                            }
                 });
    }

});

});
```

This is my controller and Model:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Updateto(GitJSON gitjson)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            gitjson.gitdList[0].AvatarURL=;


        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class gitd
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarURL { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updatedat { get; set; }


    }
public class GitJSON
{
    public List<gitd> gitdList { set; get; }
}
```

My understanding is that in the controller the GitJSON model is being binded. Therefore as a result the JSON pairs are mapped automatically to the public members of the gitd model.

After researching I came to understand that the `public List<gitd> gitdList { set; get; }`

corresponds to a list of objects which are indexed.Therefore I assume that `gitjson.gitdList[0].AvatarURL=;`  is now referring to the AvatarURL property of the first JSON object I have passed.
Is my understanding correct? If true how do I now save the JSON to the database.

Also if I put `return View();` in the Updateto controller I get a 500 error. I have not added a view to the Updateto controller.Can this be the only reason ? Also if true, shouldn't it be a Not found error instead of 500 error?

I  added a dummy view to the Updateto controller but still `return view();` gives a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Welcome to club MVC
2. you cannot return a view that does not exist, especially when client expect a json response
3. you need to map your changes to context, then you can save them

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Updateto(GitJSON gitjson)
   {
       try
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               //here is sample code to map changes to entities
               var gitdIds = gitjson.gitdList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList;

               _context.gitds
                   .Where(x => gitdIds.Contains(x.Id))
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(x =>
                   {
                       //find match data
                       var change= data.gitdList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == x.Id);
                       //update your fields here
                       x.Name = change.Name;
                               ...

                   });

                //save changes after updated entities
               await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
           return Ok();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return Json(new
           {
               error = ex.Message// or ex.ToString()
           });

           // or return RedirectToPage("Error", ex);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi,thanks a ton, without this I would not have looked at the various list operations and how I can map to the context. I have a few doubts: I am passing JSON by POSTING to the controller, therefore because of model Binding, the JSON is automatically mapped to the controller action parameter? Now when mapping , when I use the parameters of the action, I believe the data I have received by POST is present as a list in gitjson. How do I put it into the database? What does gitdds to?_context.gitds is this where I start interacting with the database? If so how come I never use gitds again?@Dongdong

Comment: Basically I believe gitjson has the list of JSON I want to insert into the database ,Now which is that database variable I use to insert the gitjson values into the database. I feel I have misunderstood a basic concept regarding this.Can you help me:)@Dongdong

Comment: if your posted json match the data structure in your action's parameter, it will be automatically. the `gitdIds` in my sample code, it's just an sample to find the index/primary keys of related rows, then you use this list to find real data in database, then map them by `ForEach`. EntityFramework will manage all changes in context, and save them to DB, no mater what operations you did, C,R,U,D, what ever. I guess you confusion is in child entities, you should do same action to them, map you json to real entities of a context.